# Error in SQL Syntax ERROR1064

Tags: mysql

Everytime I try to create the following table in MySQL command line:

```
CREATE TABLE book(
   `book_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   `isbn` char(20),
   `title` char(20),
   `author_f_name` char(20),
   `author_l_name` char(20),
   `condition` ENUM("as new","very good","good","fair","poor"),
   `price` decimal(8,2),
   `genre` char(20)
);
```

I keep getting this error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL version for the right syntax to use near 'condition ENUM("as new","very good","good","fair","poor"), price decimal(8,2), g' at line 6

I've tried using single quotes and double quotes for the ENUM options. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I believe I may have broken the question by trying to clean up the formatting. According to the error message, your placement of the backtick might be the problem. I seem to have placed them where they ought to be. Please do a rollback of the question an accept my apologies.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and clean up, the code looks good, thanks. I am not familiar with how to post code here.
Now what I don't understand is, why am I getting that error message. What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your column name is `condition`, which is a [Reserved Word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).

You need to either change the name of your column or properly quote it.

See [this thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?101,40643,40702#msg-40702) for a discussion of this very issue, which explains how to quote the column name. To quote part of the post:

> Yes, quote you identifiers.
>
> The normal quotechar is the backtick (`):
>
> create table rules (`condition` varchar(255))
>
> this is specific for mysql. ANSI SQL also defines this feature, but with the double quote (") as delimiter:
>
> create table rules ("condition" varchar(255))
>
> because the double quote is normally a string delimiter in mysql, you have to tell mysql specifically to use the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode, or just the ANSI mode.
>
> set sql_mode := 'ANSI'
>
> you can also specify tha ansi mode at server startup.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin! It works now. And thanks for informing me about the backtick and double quote.

Answer (score 1):

condition is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).